# CSS file not updating on Azure Deploy/Publish

Tags: caching, azure, cloudflare

RESOLVED
Unbeknownst to me, Cloudflare defaults to caching all css/js files for 4 hours.

Scenario:

I add this to our front page:

```
<span class="test">hullo!</span>
```

and this to our css file:

```
.test { font-size:2.0em; }
```

I do a web deploy, OR full publish to Azure and the span appears on the front page, but not the styling. The css file for some reason does not get updated. FF, IE, Chrome and Safari all confirm it. However, after a seemingly arbitrary time, the css file get updated.

Even when I remote into the Azure VM and restart the app, the styling is unchanged. The app is running on one instance, one role. No Azure Caching is setup. Adding a querystring param to the css file link does not help.  Seems like a caching issue but no clue how to resolve.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"We are using Cloudflare which has a default set up to cache all CSS and JS files. It purges the cache every 4 hours which resulted in the arbitrary updates. So, even though I was adding a new query string to the end of the css file, Cloudflare still cached the old one"

Just a quick note that you should go to CloudFlare Development Mode when making changes to the [static content files](http://support.cloudflare.com/kb/top-frequently-asked-questions/which-kind-of-file-extensions-does-cloudflare-cache) on your site. You can get to Development Mode to bypass the cache by going to: settings->Development Mode. You also have the option of purging your cache as an additional option, which we would only recommend if you really want to purge everything.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's cached by your browser. Can you please try navigate to your site and press Ctrl+F5.

Maybe you can use Fiddler to see if the CSS had been cached, or not updated, or some error when download.

Comment: Its not being cached by the browser. Ctrl+F5 does nothing and I've loaded it in Safari, a browser I've never even used before, still without the change. I've also had someone who has never visited my site check without avail. Seems like its an Azure problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved.

We are using Cloudflare which has a default set up to cache all CSS and JS files. It purges the cache every 4 hours which resulted in the arbitrary updates. So, even though I was adding a new query string to the end of the css file, Cloudflare still cached the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this and I will tell you that from my experience in Chrome you can set a setting that disables the cache in the developer tools, however, I've noticed that unless you have the dev tools window open when you hit Ctrl+F5 it doesn't reload the cache.  In IE there is a global setting in the dev tools that will make it redownload everything every time.  In Firefox there is also a setting in the dev tools that will require it to download and not use the cache.

One way that you can test this, and how I test this, is by running Fiddler and watching if it does a full download of all your files or if it's caching.

From what I've experienced is that this is truly a browser caching issue and not anything to do with Azure.

Comment: I still do not think its a browser caching issue. I asked a coworker, who has never touched the site before to go to the url. And still... the styling isnt there. The CSS file on the server shows the new styling class is there, but the span just doesnt pick it up.

Comment: On your coworkers computer, if you use Fiddler, does it show that the CSS file is downloading?  Can you access the URL of the CSS file just by navigating directly to it?